# Tensorflow: DNN library is not found but cuDNN test is successful

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Installed I have:

- TensorFlow 2.15

[image: TensorFlow 2.15]

- CUDA 12.2

[image: CUDA 12.2]

- cuDNN 8.9.7

[image: cuDNN 8.9.7]

And all seem to be working. I also see via get_build_info() the following that confirms it's all being used by tensorflow:

[image: build_info]

But when I make a model with Conv2D layers:

```
input_layer = layers.Input((32, 32, 3))
x = layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same')(input_layer)
x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = layers.LeakyReLU()(x)

x = layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same')(input_layer)
x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = layers.LeakyReLU()(x)

x = layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same')(input_layer)
x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = layers.LeakyReLU()(x)

x = layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same')(input_layer)
x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = layers.LeakyReLU()(x)

x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(128)(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = layers.LeakyReLU()(x)
x = layers.Dropout(rate=0.5)(x)

output_layer = layers.Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax')(x)

model = models.Model(input_layer, output_layer)

opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.0005)
# using categorical_crossentropy because this is a classification problem
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=1000)
```

I get the error:

```
  File "/home/jcwik/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/layers/convolutional/base_conv.py", line 262, in convolution_op

DNN library is not found.
     [[{{node model_1/conv2d_3/Conv2D}}]] [Op:__inference_test_function_11798]
```

and per Tensorflow's compatibility matrix, it should all be fine: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu